# WPF/XAML - Allowing ComboBox to have SelectedValue that isn't in ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

So, I have a customer table, containing customer records, record, each of which has a customertype field. I also have a customertype table, containing the valid values for the customertype field.

And I need a WPF to do CRUD. (Create, Review, Update, Delete).

The obvious solution is to use a ComboBox, with its SelectedValue property bound to the customertype field, and its ItemsSource property bound to a list populated by a query of the customertype table.

Problem is, this doesn't work except in the sort of simple problem that you see in exercises.

The difficulty arises when you are viewing or editing a customer record that has a customertype value that isn't in the customertype table. This can happen by error, or it can happen because the customertype has been deprecated, and removed from the table.

What WPF does, in this circumstance, is to set the customertype field to null, because the SelectedValue isn't in the ItemsSource list.  And that's a problem.

If you're only viewing, you should see the value that is in the table, regardless of whether it is in the list. If you're editing, you can make a reasonable argument that you should also show the value that is in the table, at least initially, though if you change the selection, you can't get what you started with.

So, any ideas?  This is a problem that occurs on pretty much every edit/view form I have, so I'd prefer something that is reasonably clean at point of use. (That is, given the choice of complication in the XAML, everyplace I need to handle one of these fields, or complication in the code that backs the XAML I insert to handle one of these fields, I'd prefer the latter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, I would suggest not binding your ItemsSource directly to the contents of the CustomerType table.  Instead, merge an ItemsSource for Customer Type items in the Customer Type tables AND all the CustomerType values stored in Customer records which do not exist in the Customer Type table.  Once the user goes from viewing into edit, update the collection to use only those items in the CustomerType table.  When the user goes into view mode, switch back to the merged collection.

Comment: I'm trying that, and it's not quite working. The code behind the combobox's ItemsSource now inserts the current customerid, if it's not in what is returned from the database, if we're viewing an existing record. But if I change to edit a new record, I'm raising PropertyChanged on the ItemsSource property, and in the debugger I can see the code called, and a new list constructed that doesn't include the extra value, but in the UI, I still see the first list.

Comment: Have you trie using ObservableCollection for your ItemsSource or INotifyPropertyChanged when your List collection changes?

Comment: Just a bit of mental confusion on my part.  I wasn't raising propertychanged on the property I thought I was.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above serves, it makes for a fair amount of code, in each instance. And this problem exists as a general pattern, any place where a list comes from one place and the selected value comes from another.

I've still not decided on a solution, but my latest attempt shows promise.

What I've done is to derive a new class from ComboBox. To it, I've added a new DependencyProperty - AddSelectedIfMissing. And then I override OnItemsChanged().  In it, I check to see if SelectedValue matches the SelectedValuePath field of any of the Items in ItemsSource.

I'm binding ItemsSource to a property of the viewmodel that returns a collection of record objects representing valid choices. I'm binding SelectedValue to a property of the viewmodel that contains the existing value. And I'm binding AddSelectedIfMissing to a boolean property of the viewmodel that is true when I want to add the SelectedValue to the ItemsSource.

And when I change from view to edit, I raise PropertyChanged on the property bound to ItemsSource, so the control will reload it.

What I have now has some limitations.  It depends upon being able to cast ItemsSource from object to IList, and being able to cast each item from object to a known base class that we can get field values out of.  And it'd not work if I'd bound SelectedItem, instead of SelectedValue.

But within those limitations, it's working fine.

Comment: Can you post your code for this?  I realize it is an old question, but I have a similar problem and would be interested in it.